# Can we implement azure auto heal custom action using powershell, also if that is possible what should best practice to implement it?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, kudu

I am trying to implement azure auto heal for webapps. In the actions part I want to implement custom action. Custom action will be triggering a powershell script which will be restarting our redis cache and app services.

What is the best practice to implement this? Can I store the powershell in blob or is there any other way we can restart services?

I am trying to implement it through ARM templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will you take Azure Automation into your account ? You can [create a PowerShell  runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-powershell) in it and you can [expose a webhook to trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks) it to restart your services . Besides creating webhooks for your runbook, there will be some [other ways to trigger it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/start-runbooks) .

If you have any further concerns , pls let me know .

Comment: BTW, I did some test and seems powershell scripts not work in custom action of Azure app service .

Comment: Good news ! You can use P2SEXE-GUI to convert a .ps1 file to .exe. This will be a workaround I think

Comment: I am able to convert it into exe and uploaded the same .In the Kudu console I can see the exe uploaded. I tried to run the same exe there, but nothing happens. Is there any issue if I have some characters like $$#@ in my serviceprinciplekey?

Comment: I have discussed with my colleague and we also did some test . For your requirement , Azure automation will be the best choice to meet your requirement . Running ps or ps translated exe will meet some strange errors in custom action .

Comment: Thank you @Md Farid Uddin Kiron.